# Find duplicates, display each result in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

I want to write something like this :

```
select t.id, t.name, from table t
group by t.name having count(t.name) > 1
```

To produce the following :

```
id      name  count 
904834  jim    2
904835  jim    2
90145   Fred   3
90132   Fred   3
90133   Fred   3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, Name, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) [Count]
      FROM table) t
WHERE [Count]>1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the ID column then you can get all the names that have multiple entries

```
select t.name
from table t
group by t.name
having count(t.name) > 1
```

For each name, if you want the minimum or maximum `id` you can do this

```
select t.id, t.name, min (t.id) as min_id, max (t.id) as max_id
from table t
group by t.name
having count(t.name) > 1
```

For each name, if you want all the ids that are duplicates, then you have to use a subquery

```
select t.id, t.name
from table t
where name in
(
    select t1.name
    from table t1
    group by t1.name
    having count(t1.name) > 1
)
```

Comment: thanks, but I want the id column, its kinda the point of the question

Answer (score 2):

Just join the table to a subquery pulling the count for each name

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, d.Count
FROM #MyTable t
JOIN 
(
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM #MyTable 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) D 
ON t.Name = d.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mysql (when I wrote the answer, I do not think the person specified the dbms)

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, (SELECT COUNT(t2.name) FROM test t2 ) AS t_count
FROM  test t
HAVING t_count > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous answers with less code. Tested on SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name,COUNT(*) 
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
HAVING COUNT(t.id) > 1
```

Comment: I don't think this gives the same results the OP requested.

Comment: This is my best practice for easy and fast finding duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

Please Check it once .... in SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT   t.id, 
         t.NAME, 
         Count(t.id)   AS duplicate id, 
         count(t.NAME) AS duplicate names 
FROM     t 
GROUP BY t.id, 
         t.NAME 
HAVING   count(t.NAME) > 1
```